# Why does ESLint throw error while using flow?

Tags: react-native, babeljs, eslint, flowtype

I've initialized a new react-native project with RN Version 0.59.
I've setup eslint (with airbnb-ruleset), babel and flow:

**package.json:**

```
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.4.2",
"@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.3",
"babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
"babel-jest": "^24.5.0",
"babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
"eslint": "^5.15.3",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
"flow-bin": "^0.96.0",
"jest": "^24.5.0",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
"react-test-renderer": "^16.8.5"
},
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset", "flow"]
};
```

**eslintrc.json**

```
{
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "node": true,
        "jest": true
    },
    "extends": "airbnb",
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js"] }]
    }
}
```

**Issue:**
If I run eslint, I got the following errors:

```
  8:17  error  Parse errors in imported module '../app/App': Unexpected token Props (19:6)  import/no-named-as-default
  8:17  error  Parse errors in imported module '../app/App': Unexpected token Props (19:6)  import/no-named-as-default-member
```

[image]

How can I configure eslint in right way to recognize that this is a flow-type declaration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured it out.
First I've installed `eslint-plugin-flowtype`
After that, I've edited .eslintrc.json like this:

- add `parser: "babel-eslint",`
- add to `extends`"plugin:flowtype/recommended"`
- add to `plugins` : `"flowtype"`

After that, it works.

File looks like this now:

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "node": true,
        "jest": true
    },
    "extends": "plugin:flowtype/recommended",
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "flowtype"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js"] }]
    }
}
```